# C# code structure for increased performance on querying different databases

Tags: c#, sql

Currently I am working on an application that uses multiple databases. In order to maintain the single responsibility principle, I have created a data mapper-ish structure, separating the SQL from my other code. However, although I like the structure, I am running into some performance issues. I am hoping somebody has some tips to increase the application's performance by either improving my structure or some other solution that I don't yet know of.

**Current structure**
I have two classes handling contact with my (multiple) databases: Repository and ConnectionFactory. The class Repository is created in my other code, ConnectionFactory is created by Repository in its constructor.
For example, say I have a class Person, with properties like ID, name, address, phone number, etc. In this class, if I wanted to query the name based on an ID, I would do the following:

```
int exampleID = 1;    
Repository rep = new Repository()
String name = rep.getNameByID(exampleID)
```

The Repository class contains all of my SQL code. It contains a series of methods like:

```
public String getNameByID(int id)
        {
            string conString = savedConnectionString; //this conString may vary
            string queryString = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE customerid = ?";
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);
            command.Parameters.Add("@customerid", OdbcType.Int).Value = id;
            return factory.executeScalarCommandString(conString, command);
        }
```

Then, my class ConnectionFactory handles the connection and executes the commands. It contains methods for select-commands (depending on its result type), insert, update and delete. These methods look like this:

```
public String executeScalarCommandString(String conString, OdbcCommand command)
        {
            String result = "";
            using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(conString))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    connection.Open();
                    result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

**The problem**
Initially, this structure seemed to work perfect. However, when I'm starting my program, I have a lot of data to load from multiple databses. I create the repository (which creates the ConnectionFactory), and execute a lot of methods to query my data (order of magnitude 100+). And since every method in the Repository calls a method in ConnectionFactory, and each ConnectionFactory-method opens a connection, executes a query, and closes the connection, I am opening and closing the connections for all methods. This result in the initial load of my data taking ~17 seconds, which is way too long.

**The solution?**
Since I query over different databases, I can't just open a connection in the constructor of ConnectionFactory and throw all queries over that connection. However, I think the low performance is due to the constant opening and closing of connections (correct me if I'm wrong).

Does anybody have any idea on how to increase the performance of my application? I would gladly change my structure if needed, but I like the separation of my SQL from my other code (since in the long run I want to replace the databases).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I doubt opening and closing connections multiple times is causing a problem...behind the scenes connection pooling is taking place.   "Multiple databases....lots of methods" may mean that it just takes a long time.   Have you investigated having the  methods run in parallel in separate threads?

Comment: Load data when needed and not at start up. And don't load more than needed. outside that - look if your data model is performing as needed, and profile your code to find possible bottlenecks in that.